# How do I prove that an open ball on $S^1$ divide it into two pieces?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Define $\gamma:[0,2\pi]\rightarrow S^1 : t\mapsto e^{it}$.

Let $f:S^1\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and $z_0\in S^1$.

Then it must be true that:

> There exists $\delta>0$ such that two rectifiable curves $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ such that $\int_{\gamma_1} f(z) |dz| + \int_{\gamma_2} f(z) |dz| = \int_\gamma f(z) |dz|$ and $\gamma_1 \subset \overline{B(z_0,\delta)}$ and $\gamma_2$ intersect $\overline{B(z_0,\delta)}$ only at endpoints.

This is very trivial intuitively, but how do I formally prove this? This drives me crazy..

Comment: Your statement mentions $\delta$ and then doesn't do anything with it.

Comment: @Ian Thank you. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By applying a rotation to everything, we may assume $z_0=1$.  Now consider the map $g:\mathbb{R}\to[0,\infty)$ given by $g(t)=|1-e^{it}|^2$.  We can compute $g(t)=(1-\cos t)^2+\sin^2 t=2-2\cos t$.  It now follows easily from the fact that $\cos t$ is monotone on $[0,\pi]$ and $[-\pi,0]$ that if $0<\delta<4$, then the set $g^{-1}([-\delta,\delta])\cap[-\pi,\pi]$ is a closed interval.  In your notation, this says that $\overline{B(z_0,\sqrt{\delta})}\cap S^1$ is an arc of the circle, which is what you wanted.